# String Escape for Gnuplot Data Input

Tags: string, escaping, gnuplot, data-cleaning

I'm calling gnuplot from a webserver instance through a Java environment, generating datafiles and gnuplot scripts based on data from a database and sending the resulting image to the user in an HTML page.

Is there a way to safely escape the string data to prevent gnuplot from failing no matter the input?

I'm imagining a future use-case where data might contain special characters. This applies both to the sourced datafiles used in plots and the titles injected into the gnuplot script.

Example script

```
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2 title 'My TiTlE FrOm DaTaBase'
```

data.dat:

```
"title With Spaces" 34 2 213 45 2
"title With Sp@ces" 34 3 213 45 12
"title With SpAces" 34 0 21 45 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear, because you show a wrong use for the first column, it cannot be used as x-value. Assuming, that the string in the first column should be used as xticlabel, you can use

```
set xtics noenhanced
```

to prevent gnuplot from interpreting some special characters `@{}^_` which are use for the enhanced mode:

```
set xtics noenhanced
plot 'data.dat' using 0:2:xticlabel(1)
```

Comment: Maybe the question was: "Which characters need escaping within double-quotes, and are such strings being re-interpreted after being read (a big problem is shell scripts)?